# Database Entry Error when code executed

Tags: php, mysql

```
!doctype html>
<html>
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root"); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
 $db_select = mysql_select_db("Quiz",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
?>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Quiz</title>

<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<form>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Questions`");
?>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
echo "<p class='question'>" . $row[1] . "</p>" . " <ul class='answers'>            
    <input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[2] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[2] . "</label><br/>   " . "<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[3] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[3] . "</label>   <br/>" . "<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[4] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[4] . "</label><br/>" ."<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[5] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[5] . "</label><br/>
</ul> ";        
}

mysql_free_result($result);  
?>
<input type="submit" formaction="index.php" formmethod="post">
</form>
<?php
$answer = $_POST[q1];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `User_Response`(`User_Response`) VALUES ('$answer')");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the above code, but when I check the Database the column related to User_response is null, there is just an increment in it's ID as I have set to auto-increase.

I am confuse in this regard as I have tried all the way but I am unable to resolve the query to get it work.

Comment: Try removing the backticks on (`User_Response`)

Comment: backticks? Would you be a little more expressive

Comment: Replace your code with this mysql_query("INSERT INTO `User_Response`(`User_Response`) VALUES ('$answer')");

Comment: You should start by checking the returned value of `mysql_query`. Did the call succeed? Or did it return an error?